# Deleting all C comments with sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

I am trying to write a script that will delete all comments and everything in between inside C files in my current directory. I've been using `sed`, and this is what I have so far:

```
sed -i '/ * [^()] */d' *.c
```

This works when the comments are on the same line as an asterisk or backslash.

However it doesn't work when there is a commented line without a slash or asterisk.

I know sed goes line by line, I just don't know how to tell it to keep deleting until it sees a `*/`.

Comment: Depending on what your are trying to accomplish, one possible solution to remove comments could be to run only the preprocessing step of the compilation. e.g., `gcc -E test.c > test_p.c`. This will however include header files in the C-file. Otherwise I think you are better of with some kind of utility that is capable of parsing C-files, such as some kind of beautifier.

Comment: See also: [How can I delete all characters falling under /* … */](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/297346)

Answer (score 9):

Removing comments without using a real C-preprocessor is not exactly trivial. [I once came up with something like this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=&hl=en#!msg/comp.unix.shell/J01djc0YAVg/N0LnUGFXRTcJ):

```
perl -0777 -pe'
 s{
     /\*.*?\*/
   | //[^\n]*
   | (
        "(?:\\.|.)*?"
      | '\''(?:\\.)?.*?'\''
      | \?\?'\''
      | .[^'\''"/]*
     )
  }{if ($1eq""){" "}else{$1}}exsg'
```

Which should cover most cases like things like:

```
printf("%c%c%s", '"' /* d-quote */, '\'', "/*" "*/");
```

See the interesting discussion there for more details.

Answer (score 4):

If this doesn't have to be done in `sed`, then you can do it easily with perl:

```
perl -p0i -e 's#/\*.*?\*/##sg' *.c
```

Note that this will delete parts of quoted strings that are not meant to be comments at all as in the example in the comments below.

Comment: This fails pretty spectacularly. Try this: `echo 'printf("Comments in C are written /* like this */.\n");' | perl -p0i -e 's#/\*.*?\*/##sg'`

Comment: Good point. This code does not make provisions for the case when block comments occur inside quoted text. Editing answer.

Comment: I voted your answer, although it does not cover twisted cases. using the non-greedy regex .*? is a smart trick and does the job trick for 90% of cases