# convert C style comments to C++ style using sed

Tags: sed

I'm trying to convert single line 'C' style comments to 'C++' style.  The 'sed' below isn't bad, but of course it fails if any leading code (code before the comment) has any ' / ' in it at all:

```
sed -i 's,\(^[^\/]*\)\/\*\([^\*]*\)\*\/[ ]*$,\1\/\/\2,' filename
```

What I wish I could do is this:

```
... [^\\/\\*] ...
```

i.e. negate ' /* ' which doesn't work of course, but after several hours of searching, I can't find a *simple* explanation of how to do that properly :(  It doesn't seem like it should be rocket science.

For example, these strings:

```
blah blah        /* comment */
blah blah / blah /* comment */
blah blah        /* comment */ blah
blah blah / blah /* comment */ blah
```

... should convert thusly:

```
blah blah        // comment 
blah blah / blah // comment 
blah blah        /* comment */ blah  (this CAN'T be converted)
blah blah / blah /* comment */ blah  (this CAN'T be converted)
```

... obviously no conversion can take place if there is code AFTER the 'C' comment.

I will do a close visual comparison between the file, before and after, so there's no need to handle ' /* ' inside a literal, nor do I want to convert anything multi-line.

Note I think of this as a 'negation' problem but maybe there is another way.  I  just need to capture everything before a ' /* ' and I don't care how.

#### FOLLOW UP ON ANSWER BELOW

Well damn! I see that I've completely misunderstood something fundamental:

```
.*/\*
```

... reads: "anything except slash star followed by slash star", so actually I get my 'negation' for free :-)

So, going even further than Barmar:

```
sed -i 's,^\(.*\)/\*\(.*\)\*/\s*$,\1//\2,' filename
```

... will even catch this:

```
blah / * blah        /* co / mme * nt */
```

and output this:

```
blah / * blah       // co / mme * nt
```

Enlightenment.

Comment: Why do you need to negate anything before the `/*`? Just capture everything before `/*`.

Comment: How will you handle converting multi-line `/* */` comments? What about literal strings that happen to contain `"... /* ..."`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us an example of your input and your desired output. Don't assume that text parsing experts are necessarily familiar with C or C++ syntax.

Comment: Regular expressions are useful for context-free grammars. C comments are not context-free. As comments can be in comments. `/*` can be in strings, but are not comments. etc. This question is asked regularly, unfortunately I can not remember where. The answers will tell you that regexps can not do it alone. Therefore you will need something more powerful such as `awk`.

Comment: How do you want to deal with a comment in the middle of the line? E.g.: `cout<<"a"<<endl; /* foo */ cout<<"b"<<endl;`.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72429/deleting-all-c-comments-with-sed?rq=1

Comment: @Barmar, that's exactly the problem: how?

Comment: this `.*/\*` does *not* read *anything except `/*`*, but rather *anything except **the last `/*`***. it will happily match as many intervening `/*`'s as you could want to provide it. this `[^/*]*/\*` is anything except `/` or `*` then `/*`.

Comment: @mikeserv, right you are, but your way fails to convert if there's any star or slash in the leading code, whereas my way turns " /* /* comment \*/ " into the illegal " /* // comment " (which would at least flag a compiler error).  More study ...

Comment: yeah, thats what i meant by not knowing which cases to test for. i only hoped to show how you might. if you already know that always matching the last `/*` is the way to go, then youre good to go, because `.*/\*` will get the last every time. i just wanted to make it clear that it will gobble any preceding occurrences.

Comment: Yup. Very educational tho, and thanks. I'll study your answer below, I think there's meat in that that I can now digest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed 's,^\(.*\)/\*\([^/]*\)\*/$,\1//\2,'
```

This won't convert comments that contain embedded `/` characters. Alternatively, you could use:

```
sed 's,^\(.*\)/\*\(.*\)\*/$,\1//\2,'
```

This will do the wrong thing if you have two comments on the same line, e.g.

```
blah blah        /* comment1 */ blah /* comment2 */
```

will convert to

```
blah blah       // comment1 */ blah /* comment2
```

It might be possible to do better with a PCRE version of `sed`, as you could then use negative lookahead to test for embedded comments.

Note also that using `,` as the delimiter in the `s` command means that you don't have to escape all the `/` characters in the regexp -- that's the point of using some character other than `/` as the delimiter when the regexp will contain lots of `/`.

Comment: Indeed! the slash a delimiter seems to me to be a lousy choice, I prefer the comma.

Comment: It all depends on the data you're working on. If it's English text, comma may be a poor choice.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the safest way is to first test for lines you don't want to affect and `b`ranch out of the script if you have a match.

```
sed '\|\*/.*/\*|b'
```

That's a little hard to read with all of the `*`stars in there, but basically if `/*` occurs after `*/` `sed` will quit executing its script, autoprint the line, and pull in the next line to begin the next line cycle. Any commands following that are not executed for a matching line.

Another way to do this is with `t`est, which will similarly `b`ranch out of a script if it is provided no `b`ranch label following a successful `s///`ubstitution:

```
sed 's|/\*|&|2;t'
```

That attempts to replace the second occurrence of the pattern on the line with itself, and, if successful, it branches out in the same manner `b` does.

And so...

```
sed 's|/\*|&|2;s|\*/|&|2;t
     s|/\*\(.*\)\*/ *$|//\1|'
```

...will replace the first and only occurrence of `/*` with `//` on lines which end with the first and only occurrence of `*/` and any amount of trailing space characters. This works because `t` applies to any substitution occurring before it, and so if one or the other `t`ests successful, `sed` branches out.

It may be that I blunder here, though, as I'm not very familiar with C or C++ and am uncertain what might happen in a `/\*.*\*/.*\*/` case - which the above script `b`ranches away from . Perhaps you should instead be testing for only 2 `*/` or only 2 `/*`. Hopefully, at least though, I have managed to convey the concept to one who knows better.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to need the above - but also multiline - so I merged Barmar's answer with some sed of my own to achieve this

```
sed -e '/\/\*/,/\*\//{s/^\( *\)\/\*/\1~~/g;s/^\( *\) \*\//\1~~/g;s/^\( *\) \*/\1~~/g;s/~~/\/\//g};s/\*\*/\/\//g;s,^\(.*\)/\*\(.*\)\*/\s*$,\1//\2,'
```

(BTW if on a mac, you need gsed else you will get an error from the above)

Here is a diff before/after

```
***************
*** 1,13 ****

! /*
     FOO
!  */

! /*
!  * BAR
!  */

! blah blah        /* comment */
! blah blah / blah /* comment */
  blah blah        /* comment */ blah
  blah blah / blah /* comment */ blah
--- 1,13 ----

! //
     FOO
! //

! //
! // BAR
! //

! blah blah        // comment
! blah blah / blah // comment
  blah blah        /* comment */ blah
  blah blah / blah /* comment */ blah
```