# How can I delete all characters falling under /* .... */ including /* & */?

Tags: text-processing

I did tried `sed` and `awk`, but its not working as the character involves `/` which is already there in command as delimiter.

Please let me know how can I achieve this.

Below is a sample Example. We want to remove the commented sections, i.e `/*.....*/`

```
/*This is to print the output
data*/
proc print data=sashelp.cars;
run;
/*Creating dataset*/
data abc;
set xyz;
run;
```

Comment: -bash-4.1$ sed 's,/\*.*\*/,,g' test.sas
Below is the ouput i get  , the first comment is still there.                                                                   /*This is to print the output
data*/
proc print data=sashelp.cars;
run;

data abc;
set xyz;
run;

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It would be even better if you included your desired output as well. Also include what you tried and how it failed in the question not in the comments.

Comment: What should happen to string literals containing comments or comment delimiters?  (e.g. `INSERT INTO string_table VALUES('/*'), ('*/'), ('/**/');` )

Comment: Related (sorry I can't resist!): http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48326/remove-single-line-and-multiline-comments-from-string

Comment: I updated my post with another solutions, please recheck if now it is good for you.

Comment: Hi are you still having troubles with this I write a very small C program to help me with that, can I post a new answer?

Answer (score 23):

I think i found a easy solution!

```
cpp -P yourcommentedfile.txt
```

**SOME UPDATES:**

Quote from the user **ilkachu** (original text from the user comments):

*I played a bit with the options for gcc: **-fpreprocessed** will disable most directives and macro expansions (except #define and #undef apparently). Adding **-dD** will leave defines in too; and **std=c89** can be used to ignore new style // comments. Even with them, cpp replaces comments with spaces (instead of removing them), and collapses spaces and empty lines.*

But I think it is still reasonable and a easy solution for the most of the cases, if you disable the macro expansion and other things I think you will get good results... - and yes you can combine that with shell script for getting better... and much more...

Comment: Using the C preprocessor is likely the most robust solution.  Since the preprocessor is likely the most robust parser of C comments.  Clever.

Comment: It also means if your users want to use include or ifdef they're free to. There are some X11 configuration files that use cpp for this. What's the reason for the tail command? I don't think there's anything in OP's question that calls for it.

Comment: But `cpp` will do a lot more than removing comments (process `#include`, expand macros, including builtin ones...)

Comment: The tail is for remove the things that Stéphane Chazelas said.

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini, no, `tail -n +7` will just remove the first 7 lines, it will not prevent the `#include` processing or macro expansions. Try `echo __LINE__ | cpp` for instance. Or `echo '#include /dev/zero' | cpp`

Comment: You're perfect right! But i think it will work for the user.

Comment: You probably want to use `-P` mode if you do this.  (This may eliminate the need to use `tail`.)

Comment: I played a bit with the options for gcc: `-fpreprocessed` will disable most directives and macro expansions (except `#define` and `#undef` apparently). Adding `-dD` will leave defines in too; and `std=c89` can be used to ignore new style `//` comments. Even with them, `cpp` replaces comments with spaces (instead of removing them), and collapses spaces and empty lines.

Comment: If you dont use the -P option, the white spaces not collapses.

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini but then you get the line number directives...

Comment: Yes. And you can avoid then with | tail -n+7

Comment: @ilkkachu The comments actually need to be replaced by spaces. Consider `1+/*comment*/++i`. If completely is completely collapsed, it would become `1+++i` or `((1)++) + (i)`, which is an error (`1` is an rvalue, suffix `++` requires an lvalue.) Instead, with spaces, it would be `1+ ++i`, which evaluates to `(1) + (++(i))`, which, in turn, evaluates to `(1) + ((i) += 1)` or `(1) + ((i) = (i) + 1)`.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος, If it were, C, then yes. But the question at hand does not specify this exactly, it only says the comments need to be _removed_.

Comment: @ilkkachu My statement remains true: it *could* have been C, it *might* be C. For safety, use spaces.

Comment: @ikkachu `-fpreprocessed -E` stripping comments is likely to be unintentional; don't rely on it to stay that way.

Comment: Note that that `stripcmt` fails on a few of the corner cases in the sample C file in my answer. It also turns `1 -/*comment*/-1` into `1--1` which then becomes invalid C code.

Comment: And that is what you expect when you want to remove characters falling under /*...*/... but if you are truly writing C, and removing /*...*/ is not exactly what you expect but a more intelligent behavior and this tools (and note that is a specialized tool) or C preprocessor, or sed and/or perl solutions are not enough for you maybe you should need to write your own removing comments program! I think you will agree with me, that can be so very painful that is more easy to correct the isolated generated errors than writing something like that in most of cases..

Comment: `-fpreprocessed` doesn't seem to be recognized for me on mac (Apple clang version 12.0.5)

Answer (score 11):

I once came up with [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.unix.shell/J01djc0YAVg/N0LnUGFXRTcJ) which we can refine to:

```
perl -0777 -pe '
  s{
    # /* ... */ C comments
    / (?<lc> # line continuation
        (?<bs> # backslash in its regular or trigraph form
          \\ | \?\?/
        )
        (?: \n | \r\n?) # handling LF, CR and CRLF line delimiters
      )* \* .*? \* (?&lc)* /
    | / (?&lc)* / (?:(?&lc) | [^\r\n])* # // C++/C99 comments
    | (?<code> # tokenising anything else
         "(?:(?&bs)(?&lc)*.|.)*?" # "strings" literals
       | '\''(?&lc)*(?:(?&bs)(?&lc)*(?:\?\?.|.))?(?:\?\?.|.)*?'\'' # (w)char literals
       | \?\?'\'' # trigraph form of ^
       | .[^'\''"/?]* # anything else
      )
  }{$+{code} eq "" ? " " : $+{code}}exsg'
```

to handle a few more corner cases.

Note that if you *remove* a comment, you could change the meaning of the code (`1-/* comment */-1` is parsed like `1 - -1` while `1--1` (which you'd obtain if you removed the comment) would give you an error). It's better to replace the comment with a space character (as we do here) instead of completely removing it.

The above should work properly on this valid ANSI C code for instance that tries to include a few corner cases:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  printf("%d %s %c%c%c%c%c %s %s %d\n",
  1-/* comment */-1,
  /\
* comment */
  "/* not a comment */",
  /* multiline
  comment */
  '"' /* comment */ , '"',
  '\'','"'/* comment */,
  '\
\
"', /* comment */
  "\\
" /* not a comment */ ",
  "??/" /* not a comment */ ",
  '??''+'"' /* "comment" */);
  return 0;
}
```

Which gives this output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  printf("%d %s %c%c%c%c%c %s %s %d\n",
  1- -1,
   
  "/* not a comment */",
   
  '"'   , '"',
  '\'','"' ,
  '\
\
"',  
  "\\
" /* not a comment */ ",
  "??/" /* not a comment */ ",
  '??''+'"'  );
  return 0;
}
```

Both printing the same output when compiled and run.

You can compare with the output of `gcc -ansi -E` to see what the pre-processor would do on it. That code is also valid C99 or C11 code, however `gcc` disables trigraphs support by default so it won't work with `gcc` unless you specify the standard like `gcc -std=c99` or `gcc -std=c11` or add the `-trigraphs` option).

It also works on this C99/C11 (non-ANSI/C90) code:

```
// comment
/\
/ comment
// multiline\
comment
"// not a comment"
```

(compare with `gcc -E`/`gcc -std=c99 -E`/`gcc -std=c11 -E`)

ANSI C didn't support the `// form` of comment. `//` is not otherwise valid in ANSI C so wouldn't appear there. One contrived case where `//` may genuinely appear in ANSI C (as noted [there](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.unix.shell/J01djc0YAVg/0FaDSRkPig0J), and you may find the rest of the discussion interesting) is when the *stringify* operator is in use.

This is a valid ANSI C code:

```
#define s(x) #x
s(//not a comment)
```

And at the time of the discussion in 2004, `gcc -ansi -E` did indeed expand it to `"//not a comment"`. However today, `gcc-5.4` returns an error on it, so I'd doubt we'll find a lot of C code using this kind of construct.

The GNU `sed` equivalent could be something like:

```
lc='([\\%]\n|[\\%]\r\n?)'
sed -zE "
  s/_/_u/g;s/!/_b/g;s/</_l/g;s/>/_r/g;s/:/_c/g;s/;/_s/g;s/@/_a/g;s/%/_p/g;
  s@\?\?/@%@g;s@/$lc*\*@:&@g;s@\*$lc*/@;&@g
  s:/$lc*/:@&:g;s/\?\?'/!/g
  s#:/$lc*\*[^;]*;\*$lc*/|@/$lc*/([\\\\%].|[^\\\\%\n\r])*|(\"($lc|[\\\\%]$lc*[^\r\n]|[^\\\\%\"])*\"|'$lc*([\\\\%]$lc*[^\r\n])?([^\\\\%']|$lc)*'|$lc|[^'\"@;:]+)#<\5>#g
  s/<>/ /g;s/!/??'/g;s@%@??/@g;s/[<>@:;]//g
  s/_p/%/g;s/_a/@/g;s/_s/;/g;s/_c/:/g;s/_r/>/g;s/_l/</g;s/_b/!/g;s/_u/_/g"
```

If your GNU `sed` is too old to support `-E` or `-z`, you can replace the first line with:

```
sed -r ":1;\$!{N;b1}
```

Comment: perl solution have problem with multi line: test it with this output => echo -e "BEGIN/*comment*/ COMMAND /*com\nment*/END"

Comment: @Babby, works for me. I've added a multi-line comment and the resulting output in my test case.

Comment: The best thing to compare to nowadays would be `gcc -std=c11 -E -P` (`-ansi` is just another name for `-std=c90`).

Comment: @zwol, the idea is to be able to handle code written for any C/C++ standard (c90, c11 or other). Strictly speaking, it's not possible (see my 2nd contrived example). The code still tries to handle C90 constructs (like `??'`), hence we compare with `cpp -ansi` for those and C99/C11... one (like `// xxx`), hence we compare with `cpp` (or `cpp -std=c11`...)

Comment: @zwol, I've split the test case in an attempt to clarify a bit. It looks like trigraphs are still in C11, so my second test case is not standard C anyway.

Comment: Right, as far as I know the only official change since C90 in this area is the introduction of // comments in C99.  GCC's default non-conversion of trigraphs is an independent thing.

Comment: @zwol, I've removed that case as it was hardly even an academic one. I've replaced with the one that was referred to in the 2004 discussion (academic as well)

Comment: That `sed` expression near the end scares me. I wonder if, like monsters under the bed, it goes away if you look at it and then scroll away?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, you'll find that it's a lot more straightforward (though less portable) than the (clever) approach at http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/scripts/remccoms3.sed

Answer (score 6):

with `sed`:

#### UPDATE

```
/\/\*/ {
    /\*\// {
        s/\/\*.*\*\///g;
        b next
    };

    :loop;
    /\*\//! {
        N;
        b loop
    };
    /\*\// {
        s/\/\*.*\*\//\n/g
    }
    :next
}
```

support all possible (multi line comment, data after [or and] befor, );

```
 e1/*comment*/
-------------------
e1/*comment*/e2
-------------------
/*comment*/e2
-------------------
e1/*com
ment*/
-------------------
e1/*com
ment*/e2
-------------------
/*com
ment*/e2
-------------------
e1/*com
1
2
ment*/
-------------------
e1/*com
1
2
ment*/e2
-------------------
/*com
1
2
ment*/e2
-------------------
```

run:

```
$ sed -f command.sed FILENAME

e1
-------------------
e1e2
-------------------
e2
-------------------
e1

-------------------
e1
e2
-------------------

e2
-------------------
e1

-------------------
e1
e2
-------------------

e2
-------------------
```

Comment: won't work for a comment starting after data, like `proc print data 2nd /*another comment is here*/`

Comment: @mazs  updated, check it

Comment: This does not handle comments inside string literals, which may actually matter, depending on what the SQL does

Answer (score 4):

```
 $ cat file | perl -pe 'BEGIN{$/=undef}s!/\*.+?\*/!!sg'

 proc print data=sashelp.cars;
 run;

 data abc;
 set xyz;
 run;
```

Remove blank lines if any:

```
 $ cat file | perl -pe 'BEGIN{$/=undef}s!/\*.+?\*/\n?!!sg'
```

Edit - the shorter version by Stephane:

```
 $ cat file | perl -0777 -pe 's!/\*.*?\*/!!sg'
```

Comment: well, I agree with terdon: Lets see the expected output.

Comment: BTW: What should happen to a single line containing: "/*foo*/run;/*bar*/" ? Should that just be "run;" ?

Comment: Great! Then my solution works. Note I use non-greedy: ".+?"

Comment: It looks fine i will test it!

Comment: See `-0777` as a shorter way to do `BEGIN{$/=undef}`

Comment: Perhaps  `.*?` instead of `.+?` if `/**/` is a valid comment too.

Comment: This perl command works for me .Thanks a lot                                               However removing blank line is not working..

Answer (score 2):

## Solution by Using SED command and no Script

Here you are:

`sed 's/\*\//\n&/g' test | sed '/\/\*/,/\*\//d'`

**N.B.** This doesn't work on OS X, unless you install `gnu-sed`. But it works on Linux Distros.

Comment: you can use `-i` option to edit file in-place instead of redirecting output to new file. or much safer `-i.bak` to backup file

Comment: It is not working for all the cases too, try to put a comment in the same line and watch what happens... Example set xy\; /*test*/  I think we will need perl too solve this in a easy way.

Comment: @Rahul exactly, thanks for mentioning. I just wanted to keep it more simple.

Comment: Im very sorry to say that it is not working for comments in the same line.

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini Now it does!

Comment: @FarazX: No, it doesn't.

Comment: @Scott I've tested on RHEL 7 and Kali 2, and it worked, but it won't work if you're trying to use `sed -e  's/\*\//\n&/g' -e '/\/\*/,/\*\//d' test`, it needs a pipe. because first of all, we need to add a newline when there are comments starting and ending in the same line, so it can get it as a range with a starting/ending point since it checks newlines. I'm not sure why it doesn't work for you, but it does for me. I just tested now again to make sure, and it did work. Anyway, Luciano is right, perl can be better and easier, but I prefer sed itself.

Comment: I suspect we’re chasing different test cases.  My issue is that a line `abc /* def */ ghi` gets completely deleted, while (IMO) it should leave `abc ghi`.  Admittedly, it is an unfortunate nuisance that the OP hasn’t posted expected output, hasn’t addressed edge cases, and seems to have abandoned this question.

Comment: @Scott Indeed, in that case you're utterly right mate.

Comment: Try using `\r` instead of `\n` in the replacement pattern.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` operates on one line at a time, but some of the comments in the input span multiple lines.  As per https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152389/90751 , you can first use `tr` to turn the line-breaks into some other character.  Then `sed` can process the input as a single line, and you use `tr` again to restore the line-breaks.

```
tr '\n' '\0' | sed ... | tr '\0' \n'
```

I've used null bytes, but you can pick any character that doesn't appear in your input file.

`*` has a special meaning in regular expressions, so it will need escaping as `\*` to match a literal `*`.

`.*` is [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) -- it will match the longest possible text, including more `*/` and `/*`.  That means the first comment, the last comment, and everything in between.  To restrict this, replace `.*` with a stricter pattern: comments can contain anything that's not a "*", and also "*" followed by anything that's not a "/".  Runs of multiple `*`s also have to be accounted for:

```
tr '\n' '\0' | sed -e 's,/\*\([^*]\|\*\+[^*/]\)*\*\+/,,g' | tr '\0' '\n'
```

This will remove any linebreaks in the multiline comments, ie.

```
data1 /* multiline
comment */ data2
```

will become

```
data1  data2
```

If this isn't what was wanted, `sed` can be told to keep one of the linebreaks.  This means picking a linebreak replacement character that can be matched.

```
tr '\n' '\f' | sed -e 's,/\*\(\(\f\)\|[^*]\|\*\+[^*/]\)*\*\+/,\2,g' | tr '\f' '\n'
```

The special character `\f`, and the use of a back-reference that may not have matched anything, aren't guaranteed to work as intended in all `sed` implementations.  (I confirmed it works on GNU sed 4.07 and 4.2.2.)

Comment: Could you please let mne know how it will work .I tried as below.                                              tr '\n' '\0' | sed -e 's,/\*\([^*]\|\*\+[^*/]\)*\*\+/,,g' test.sas | tr '\0' '\n'  and i got as below:                                                                                                   /*This is to print the output
data*/data abcdf;
set cfgtr;
run;
proc print data=sashelp.cars;
run;

data abc;
set xyz;
run;

Comment: @ShariqueAlam You've put `test.sas` in the middle of the pipeline there, so `sed` reads from it directly, and the first `tr` has no effect.  You need to use `cat test.sas | tr ...`

Answer (score 0):

using one line sed to remove comments:

```
sed '/\/\*/d;/\*\//d' file

proc print data=sashelp.cars;
run;
data abc;
set xyz;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU awk manual provides [an example with getline](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Plain-Getline.html) that does just that, which I copy here verbatim.

```
# Remove text between /* and */, inclusive
{
    while ((start = index($0, "/*")) != 0) {
        out = substr($0, 1, start - 1)  # leading part of the string
        rest = substr($0, start + 2)    # ... */ ...    
        while ((end = index(rest, "*/")) == 0) {  # is */ in trailing part?
            # get more text
            if (getline <= 0) {
                print("unexpected EOF or error:", ERRNO) > "/dev/stderr"
                exit
            }
            # build up the line using string concatenation
            rest = rest $0
        }
        rest = substr(rest, end + 2)  # remove comment
        # build up the output line using string concatenation
        $0 = out rest
    }
    print $0
}
```

Bear in mind that it joins `mon/*comment*/key` into `monkey`. As Stéphane Chazelas mentions in this answer, this may lead to an effectively different code, so consider changing `$0 = out rest` to `$0 = out " " rest`.

Save that in a file, say `commentRemove.awk`, and execute it on a `inputfile`:

```
awk -f commentRemove.awk inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using cpp (preprocessor) ?

```
( sed "s,^\(\s*\)#,\1_:#:_," \
| sed "s,\\\\$,_:%:_," \
| cpp \
| sed "/^\s*#/ d" \
| sed "s,^\(\s*\)_:#:_,\1#," \
| sed "s,_:%:_$,\\\\," \
) < in.c > out.c
```