# Remove comments in a C file

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep, source-code

I am trying to remove comments from a file which may be in any part of a line and span multiple lines.

```
 struct my_struct{
  field1;
  field2; /** comment 1
  */ field3;
  /* comment 2 */
 } struct_name;
```

I need to get

```
struct my_struct{
  field1;
  field2; 
  field3;
 } struct_name;
```

I tried using

```
grep -o '[^/*]*[^*/]'
```

to remove any text between matching /* and */, but it is eliminating the comment symbols but not the text in between. What is the correct way? If there is another way using 'sed', it would be nice to know that too.

Comment: I doubt you can do it in grep, as it matches line-by-line. awk is definitely possible, and sed may be too.

Comment: Also: [How can I delete all characters falling under /\* … \*/ including /* & */?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/297346/170373)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to remove anything between `/*` and `*/`, and ignore all the quirks of the C language, like C99-style `//`-comments, quoted strings and backslash-escapes of newlines, then a simple Perl-regex should do:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's,/\*.*?\*/,,gs' inputfile
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a *C compiler* : [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc) :

```
gcc -fpreprocessed -dD -E -P file.c
```

check `man gcc`

Comment: Some discussion on the ups and downs of using `cpp` for that, here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/297375/170373

Comment: Yes, check this one especially: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297346/how-can-i-delete-all-characters-falling-under-including/297375#comment522655_297375

Comment: This too: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297346/how-can-i-delete-all-characters-falling-under-including/297375#comment523813_297375