# extract include in C file

Tags: grep, perl, c

I need to extract all included libraries in a C file, but I got some problems. My solution for this is so:

```
grep -oP '#(?:\/\*\w*\*\/|)include(?:\/\*\w*\*\/|\s*)"\w*.h"|<\w*.h>' main.c
```

This regex takes library when it is in comment, for example

```
/*#include <stdlib.h>*/
```

and I don't know how to make that script gives me only name of library without #include

How to fix my regex to it work right?

UPD:

main.c

```
#include  "string.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
 #include "math.h"
    #include "stdint.h"
#/*comment*/include /*comment*/ <fenv.h>  
//#include <iostream>
#/**/include "something.h"
/* comment */#include "float.h"
/*#include "library.h"*/
int main() {

}
```

What I want:

```
"string.h"
<stdlib.h>
"math.h"
"stdint.h"
<fenv.h>
"something.h"
"float.h"
```

Comment: Only match lines that *begin* with `#`, maybe?

Comment: @larsks i wont to get this - /* some comment*/#include <stdlib.h>  to

Comment: @user401689  do you wan't something like `sed -n 's/.*\(<.*>\).*/\1 /p' main.c` ?

Comment: @val0x00ff this is no correct for this - /* #include <stdlib.h> */, i wont take in fact include libraries

Comment: @user401689 it would be good idea to post sample of input lines and corresponding output for whatever cases you can think of... that way it would be clearer than possible ambiguity...

Comment: If you _really_ have lines with comments before include-directives, but you only want the directives itself (as opposed to full lines or other context), you need to [remove the comments](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317795/remove-comments-in-a-c-file) first, and then look for the directives. Given all the quirks of the C language, that's not as trivial as it seems. `#if` blocks will be your next problem

Comment: Now this guy got me lost. *plunk*

Answer (score 6):

You should ask the compiler (or rather, the C pre-processor) to do the work for you:

```
gcc -M main.c
```

This will produce a Makefile-style dependency with all the headers included by `main.c` (including those included transitively). It will correctly handle comments and other pre-processor directives (`#if`, `#ifdef` and so on).