# Replacing every line of pattern block with EOL

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a text file as shown below:

*where $ tells about EOL (end of line) location I have used to illustrate that.*

```
 53t83t5  5 gejgi3 gg 4gij503 $

      /* rtdrfsetsrhs               $
ryhrdhrh               $
rhyrdhyyyyyyyyyyyrhyrshrh$
ryhrhrh */$
$
345dfeb terfgb$
/*srdtfgyhgfs*/           $
$
$
```

Now I have to replace every line of `/* */` this block with EOL placed at start of the line as shown below, Notice the position of $ for **Line 3** that means if there are some characters including whitespace we should not skip it instead we should place EOL at the position of `/*` forward slash.

```
 53t83t5  5 gejgi3 gg 4gij503 $

      $
$
$
$
$
345dfeb terfgb$
/*srdtfgyhgfs*/           $
$
$
```

I was able to detect the block using `sed '/\/\*/,/\*\//d inputFile` even I was able to delete the whole block also but I wonder can we do the above one using sed command in .sed script.

**NOTE:**  `/*...*/` this is used for illustration of a pattern block we can have different pattern enclosing blocks also, like `<--...-->` or `!!...!!` however I want to know a snippet for `/*...*/`, I can handle all others on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it has to be `sed`, the following script does as per your example:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/sed -f

# if line contains "/*" we enter our "within-patterns" code-block
/\/\*/{
# however, lines must also _not_ contain "*/",
# because our specs wants us to leave those lines as is
    /\*\//!{
# first line within patterns, delete everything after the "/*"
        s%/\*.*%%
# this is a label to be used by "goto" (sed's 'b' command)
        :block
# display current line and read next one
        n
# if line just read does _not_ have "*/" end-of-block
        /\*\//!{
# delete whole line and
            s/.*//
# "goto" label "block" above
            bblock
        }
# we get here if current line _does_ contain "*/" end-of-block,
# in which case we delete everything up to the "*/"
        s%.*\*/%%
# then exit our "within-patterns" code-block.
    }
}
```

The approach is by having the script keep control over the looping while it is in "within block" mode, instead of letting `sed` do it automatically. This way we fine tune the manipulation of the lines within a block.

Note however that this is only for instructional purposes so to introduce *a bit* of more advanced `sed` constructs. This script would not be fully appropriate to parse comment lines out from actual C/XML/HTML/whatever source files, because those are typically much more complex than your sample scenario. See for instance [this Q&A for more insight](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/297346/342404).

Answer (score 1):

From your expected output, it looks like you want to delete all but newline characters from the blocks that contain at least one newline character.

So you could use `perl` as:

```
perl -0777 -pe '
  s{/\* .*? \*/ | <-- .*? --> | !! .*? !!}{
    $& =~ /\n/ ? $& =~ s/[^\n]//gr : $&
  }gsex' < your-file
```