# Trying to use a Regex \/\*(.|\n)*?\*\/ to select every C multiline comment but its not working in SED

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I need to match the C styled multiline comment for eg.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // this is a dummy function
    float sum = 0;
    // testing the sed commands
    
    int x = 6; // single-line comment
    x = x + 5;
    
    char y = 'n'; /* end of c  *
    file */
}
```

I need to delete all multi-line comments.

So I used `sed s/\/\*\(.\|\n\)*\?\*\///`, but it doesn't work.
I tried replacing `/` with `%`: `s%\/\*\(.\|\n\)*\?\*\/%%` but it still isn't working.

Can anyone please help to put this regex `\/\*(.|\n)*?\*\/` operation in `sed` command?

Comment: Already answered.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061785/remove-multi-line-comments

Comment: That didn't helped much.

Comment: What operating system are you using? We need to know this to know what `sed` you have.

Comment: well, usually when you end up at "but it doesn't work", it's time to look at the error message and figure out what it might mean. _And to include it in the question_ when you ask for help, so others don't need to guess out everything from zero. Here, you need quotes to protect the sed command from the shell. Without them, sed sees `s//*(.|n)*?*///`. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/170373, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/400447/170373, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/503013/170373

Comment: In any case, removing comments from C code according to all the actual syntax rules, is hideously hard to get right, see e.g. [Deleting (some) comments from a C program](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/520422/deleting-some-comments-from-a-c-program), [Deleting all C comments with sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72429/deleting-all-c-comments-with-sed), and esp. Stéphane's answer in [How can I delete all characters falling under /* … */ including /* & */?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297346/how-can-i-delete-all-characters-falling-under-including)

Comment: I am using ubuntu 18.04. That Regex is working fine. But inside SED its unable to detect the match. It doesn't throws any error. I am allowed to use SED only and no any other software.

Comment: without quotes, GNU sed says `sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unknown option to 's'` because there's `s//...///`, i.e. extra slashes after the `s///`. Unless your shell is something funky, that is, but the other common not-so-POSIX shells like fish, Zsh and tcsh would complain about that glob not matching anything.

Comment: @TusharAmdoskar, you're "allowed to"? So, what are the _exact_ requirements and restrictions then? Standard POSIX sed? GNU sed (the one you have on Ubuntu)? Multi-line comments _only_, or single-line and multi-line comments both? That last `\/\*(.|\n)*?\*\/` looks a lot like a Perl-style regex that would match single and multi-line comments. Please [edit] your answer to include the constraints, comments are mostly just good for stuffing information out of sight.

Comment: @TusharAmdoskar, and, I'm sorry if that came out too harshly. It's just that the problem with unix-likes is that they're _different_, not all systems tools that support all the same features. Standard POSIX features vs. GNU extensions being a big one. Also, when you say you're _allowed_ to only use X, it makes it sound like a course assignment. And the problem with _those_, is that they're often disconnected from real-world problems. In the real-world, it's often better to find a tool that works best for the job, while assignments can have arbitrary limitations like that.

Comment: Let alone the actually hairy stuff you get in the real world, like the fact that (in C++ or C99) `// hi /* there` is not the start of a `/*` -style comment, and `printf("/* hello */");` also contains comments.

Answer (score 1):

Sed works on "records" (lines) which are defined by the presence of a trailing newline (`\n`) character. This means you cannot match past a `\n` because as far as `sed` is concerned, the `\n` is the end of the record. You can get around this, in GNU `sed`, by using `-z` to slurp the file and treat the entire thing as a single record (unless your file has NULLs (`\0`) in it, in which case each `\0` will define a record):

```
$ sed -zE 's|/\*.*\n.*\*/||' file.c 
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // this is a dummy function
    float sum = 0;
    // testing the sed commands
    
    int x = 6; // single-line comment
    x = x + 5;
    
    char y = 'n'; 
}
```

However, this will fail if you have multiple multi-line comments in the same file because `sed` cannot do non-greedy matching, so it will always try and find the *longest* possible match which means it would match from the first `/*` to the last `*/`. So use a tool that can do non-greedy matching, like `perl`:

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's|/\*.*?\n.*?\*/||gs' file.c 
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // this is a dummy function
    float sum = 0;
    // testing the sed commands
    
    int x = 6; // single-line comment
    x = x + 5;
    
    char y = 'n'; 
}
```

This, however, will fail if you have a single line `/* */` comment. The safest way I can think of is to forget about trying to do this with regular expressions and instead write a little script that keeps count of opening and closing comment tags and deletes accordingly.

Another problem is that a string with `/*` or `*/` will also break it. For example, what if you have something  like:

```
char foo [ ] = "A comment starts with /*";
```

At the end of the day, the only safe way of doing this will be something like [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13062682/1081936) by [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) which uses a C preprocessor:

> If this is in a C file then you MUST use a C preprocessor for this in
> combination with other tools to temporarily disable specific
> preprocessor functionality like expanding #defines or #includes, all
> other approaches will fail in edge cases. This will work for all
> cases:
>
> ```
> [ $# -eq 2 ] && arg="$1" || arg=""
> eval file="\$$#"
> sed 's/a/aA/g; s/__/aB/g; s/#/aC/g' "$file" |
>           gcc -P -E $arg - |
>           sed 's/aC/#/g; s/aB/__/g; s/aA/a/g'
> ```
>
> Put it in a shell script and call it with the name of the file you
> want parsed, optionally prefixed by a flag like "-ansi" to specify the
> C standard to apply.
>
> See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35708616/1745001 for details.

Comment: maybe just `perl -0777 -pe 's|/\*.*?\*/||gs'`, since they already had `(.|\n)*?` in the question (and `.` matches `\n` when `/s` is in effect IIRC). `s|/\*.*?\n.*?\*/||gs` has the problem that it eats lines uncommented lines between _single-line comments_, since it demands to find a newline. Change the `//` comments to `/* .. */` to see.

Comment: Crap. You're right about the single line comments, @ilkkachu, but the question states "multiline" comments (see question title and "*I need to delete all multi-line comments*"), so I think the `\n` is needed. I have to find another workaround so it doesn't eat the uncommented lines between single-line comments.

Comment: something like `s,/\* (.(?!\*/))* \n ((.|\n)*?)  \*/,,gmx` came to mind. Or maybe it's simpler to do  `s,/\* (.*?)  \*/, $1 =~ /\n/ ? "" : $& ,gsxe`.

Comment: @ilkkachu neither of those seems to work. Time to post your answer! >:)

Comment: Also might mention _strings_ with `/*` in them might confuse things. Things like these are best done with a C preprocessor.

Comment: @Kusalananda very true. Answer edited.

Comment: @Kusalananda.  ANTLR is an excellent alternative to the C preprocessor for this purpose.